# Adding aspect logging throws bean instantiation exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I have a simple service where I want to do logging via Spring AOP. I am getting bean when running it, I have bean for restTemplate in controller already defined, please suggest if missing anything here.

Stack trace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demo1Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/test/demo1/controller/Demo1Controller.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'demo1Controller' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'restTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My aspect class DemoHttpAspect.java

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(1)
public class DemoHttpAspect {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoHttpAspect.class);

    
    @After("execution(public * com.test.demo1.controller.*.*(..))")
    public void logAfter() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(SplunkLogImpl.of("Performance Logging via AspectJ, Into DemoAspect"));
        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest();

        HttpAspectCore.controllerEvents(request);
        System.out.println(SplunkLogImpl.of("Performance Logging via AspectJ, Out of CoreAspect"));
    }
    
}
```

My Controller class

```
package com.test.demo1.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


@RestController
public class Demo1Controller {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
 
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate()
    {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
 
    @RequestMapping("/demo1/name")
    public String getMicroserviceName()
    {
          String micro2Response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8084/service/sleuth", null, String.class);
          System.out.println("getMicroserviceName");
        return "Demo" + " : " + micro2Response ;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/demo1/sleuth")
    public String helloSleuth(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
        System.out.println("helloSleuth");
        System.out.println("headers.getClass()"+headers.getClass());
        return "success demo1";
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't put `Bean` methods in components. Remove it (and it will also solve your issue).

Comment: @M.Deinum, if I remove annotation, it gives : Description:

Field restTemplate in com.test.demo1.controller.Demo1Controller required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' in your configuration.

Comment: sir, if commented the "//@Component" in aspect and it started working but aspect logging is not working not sure if that is needed for Aspect.

Answer (score 3):

Your Demo1Controller depends on restTemplate but it also define it as a [lite bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts). So you have a circular dependency you need Demo1Controller to create restTemplate but Demo1Controller needs restTemplate.

You have two solutions:

1. move the @Bean definition to a @Configuration class
2. make the method static.

The first solution is the recommended one in this case.

```java
@Configuration
public class DepsConfig {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}

@RestController
public class Demo1Controller {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
 
    @RequestMapping("/demo1/name")
    public String getMicroserviceName()
    {
          String micro2Response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8084/service/sleuth", null, String.class);
          System.out.println("getMicroserviceName");
        return "Demo" + " : " + micro2Response ;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/demo1/sleuth")
    public String helloSleuth(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
        System.out.println("helloSleuth");
        System.out.println("headers.getClass()"+headers.getClass());
        return "success demo1";
    }
}
```

Because you are using spring boot, I suppose you use the default ComponantScanning meaning the DepsConfig should be in the package (or sub-package) where the application is defined.

I suggest you look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#spring-core) on how IoC work with spring and how to define beans. And how spring boot autoconfiguration works.

Comment: Using "@Configuration" gives, Multiple markers at this line
 - Configuration cannot be resolved to a type
 - The annotation @Configuration is disallowed for this 
  location

Comment: it should be use on a class

Comment: sorry did not get you, I am using it in Controller class, can you please elaborate on what you meant.

Comment: I updated my answer but this is really basic spring.

Comment: I think if I understood what "M. Deinum" said, I should not have used "@Bean" in the "@Component" class which was causing the issue and if I split it as you said in DepsConfig, it works. Not sure but why it is needed in the separate class ?

Comment: My first paragraph explain it.

Comment: Actually, even the error message vicky posted already suggests what JEY explained in more detail here as one possible solution: _"Circular reference involving containing bean 'demo1Controller' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance."_ Sometimes it helps to really just read the error message. As for _"Configuration cannot be resolved to a type"_, maybe just import the correct class. Your IDE should help you and suggest one automatically.